# Firefox addon doesn't work when using % in menu label and tooltip

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, dtd, browser-addons

I am working on a firefox addon, and when I use % for a menu label and tooltip the addon doesn't work (doesn't show up on firefox).

I am using the % in a .dtd file like this:

```
<!ENTITY addonName.menuX "%09 (Tab)">
```

And in the .xul file like this:

```
<menuitem class="menuitem-iconic" image="chrome://addonName/skin/image.png" tooltiptext="&addonName.menuX;" label="&addonName.menuX;" oncommand="addonName.function( 'X' )" />
```

If I delete the % from `<!ENTITY addonName.menuX "%09 (Tab)">` it works fine. I tried escaping it with a backslash but still doesn't work, so how do I print % in the addon menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unicode equivalent of % which is `\u0025`  should work.