# How to place a carriage return in the text for an ENTITY?

Tags: css, firefox-addon, dtd

In my `dtd` file for my localization strings for the xul of my addon, I have a very long string in which I need a carriage return.

```
<!ENTITY myentity.label "THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM. **break** REPEAT: THIS IS ONLY A TEST.">
```

What can I put in please of `break` in my example?
My dtd file is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM.

I've tried (in place of the `break`):
`\u000D`
`\u000D\u000A`
`&#xa;`
`%0D%0A`

And I've tried adding a literal carriage return, too.

```
<!ENTITY myentity.label "THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM.
REPEAT: THIS IS ONLY A TEST.">
```

but when the string shows in the dialogue window in Firefox, it still shows as one long line with no breaks - which means the text runs off the edge of the dialogue box.

It seems like [I should use the unicode code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496078/firefox-addon-doesnt-work-when-using-in-menu-label-and-tooltip?rq=1) for the character, but when I add that, it just prints literally.

Comment: Have you tried `<!ENTITY myentity.label "THIS IS A TEST OF THE EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM.\nREPEAT: THIS IS ONLY A TEST.">`

Comment: Yes, it just prints the \n right in the string!

Comment: No, that gives up an xml parsing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a carriage return in an entity directly.

If the entity is the text content of a `<description>`, you can add `xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` to your window or overlay definition and then use `<html:br/>` in your entity.

The preferred way to do what you are trying to do is to set a max width on the XUL description entry via CSS and allow it to wrap. For this to work, the text must be a child of the description (not the value attribute).

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/description

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I was looking for - the way to add the html into the entity; however, I did, finally did set the width property on the description tag.